# Haircare for long rough male hair

Tags: hair

I have been growing my hair for a year or so, and it has reached quite some length. Problem is that my hair is really rough and dry. While it remains fine the day I wash them with shampoo and use conditioner, the next day it starts getting entangled and breaking.

I would like to know how men with long hair deal with this? What are some of the solutions? You could answer either of these:

- Are there some special hair post-washing products that should be used in such cases?
- Should I change my hair washing routine? (Currently it is twice a week)
- Should I use some special kind of shampoos and conditioner?

Comment: Do you have wavy/curly hair? If so, don't brush it and don't comb it, except with your fingers. As for using shampoo I don't think I would use it at all if it didn't start to itch, because it always looks much better after a few days without.

Comment: Yes @Andreas. My hair are slightly wavy. And thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't sound as if your conditioner is doing the job at all well, you may need a different one, preferably one with 'smoothing' qualities - these are usually sold with a description along the lines of 'sleek and smooth'. Maybe you're using a high detergent level shampoo too - when you choose a shampoo, smell it - those with high detergent levels can be detected by the nose and smell a bit like washing up liquid and should be avoided. This only works if you have a reasonably good sense of smell, obviously, and men often don't have (no criticism, just a fact) so maybe ask a woman to smell it for you if that's the case for you. Expensive shampoos MIGHT have less detergent, but not necessarily. Either way, pick a shampoo that's gentle (sniff those too, even shampoos for babies vary), wash the hair and when you condition, and using a wide tooth comb, comb the conditioner through and leave it on for 10 to 30 minutes, then rinse off.

This next part is the only bit that might fit into the 'Hack' category, because you might have it in the kitchen cupboard already. Ordinary coconut oil is a good restorative for use on dry, rough hair, but use it on dry, not wet, hair - warm it slightly to melt it, and apply liberally to all the hair, wrap the hair round your head and then wrap in a towel or cling film, leave it on all night, wash and condition as usual the next day. You may find you need to wash it twice to clear away the oil. Repeat this treatment periodically, when you notice your hair looks dry and rough again.

Comment: Thanks. That is some good advice. Next time I go to the store, I'll read the ingredients/instructions carefully. The coconut advice is also a good one. I'll try to follow up on it right away.

Comment: The ingredients don't usually clarify the detergent content - that's the last thing they want you to know! They might list it as surfactant I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use **Aloe vera**

[image: Aloe vera plant]

You can use the aloe directly from a plant or find 100% bottled aloe vera. Apply the liquid gel to your hair, massaging it in around the roots and working towards the tips. Let this sit in your hair for 15 to 30 minutes, and then rinse it out followed by your regular hair wash using shampoo and conditioner.

Source: [wikihow](http://m.wikihow.com/Make-Your-Hair-Soft-and-Silky)

Answer (score 1):

You can

- Avoid shampooing your hair daily.
- After washing your hair, take 2 egg whites and apply it to your hair. Wait for 10 mins and rinse thoroughly. This will improve shine and prevent breakage.
- Before going to bed, massage your scalp and hair with coconut oil, wash your hair the next morning.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But if I don't wash my hair for 3 days or so, I begin to feel some itch. So, maybe I will not wash daily, but is washing twice or thrice a week okay?

Comment: washing on alternate days is the best IMHO.